# How to embed / play Larger .mp4 videos on the ipad

Tags: html, ipad, video, mp4

**iPad/iPad 2 Supported Video Format**

H.264 video up to 720p, 30 frames per second, Main Profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;

MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;

Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format.

**And mine is below:**

```
  <video width="968" height="768" id="exjadeVideo">
  <source src="video/animation_4000kbps.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

I don't want to loose the quality, or size; ideally -- any possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check the width-height of "animation_4000kbps.mp4", since height,width parameter in HTML code only set the display size of browser and not the original video.

Comment: Yes. I thought the problem may be that Video is too large in both display dimensions and weight -- but after trying an online compressor -- and compressing it to the ipad specs; it still doesn't display!

Comment: can you post the exact spec of animation_4000kbps.mp4, using ffmpeg or vlc